# SELECTing from multiple views

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am pulling information from a database by using views. In the aforementioned views, I need to have another layer which is responsible from picking information from the views.

The views are pretty large, and have mostly the same types of information in them (there are a few flags which are responsible from picking the correct type of information for a specific layer).

Visualize for example the different layers in merchandise. You get a pallet (view3) of items, each item is wrapped in a case (view2), this case holds x items, and the items are the base layer (view1).

Example:

```
View1(single item)    View2 (multiple items)    View3 (all items)
10 cols               8 cols                    4 cols
```

What's special about my views, is that most of the columns have the same name in all three views. So a column named "Name" would be the same in View1, View2 and View3, but the different physical layers are different in the amount of information that's pulled from each one.

Should I just scrap this, and put everything inside one view, and then select on the flags from there?

The sql responsible for pulling the information from the views is supposed to be a stored procedure. You input an id and a region code, and is presented with all the different layers for the item.

Comment: Most of the columns have the same name is not the same as all.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really provided enough data about

- How the 3 views are built (i.e. what and where they select from)
- How the underlying table data is stored

But this seems like a pretty standard `1:N:M` relationship structure but I would consider a data structure like this.

**Tables**

```
Items                               Cases                            Pallets
-------------------------           -------------------              ----------------------
Id        INT PK NOT NULL   +------> Id          INT PK NOT NULL +--> Id            INT PK NOT NULL
ItemCode  NVARCHAR(50)      |        CaseBarCode NVARCHAR(50)    |    PalletBarCode NVARCHAR(50)
ItemName  NVARCHAR(50)      |        PalletId    FK to Pallets --+
CaseID    FK To Cases ------+
```

With that type of a table data structure, it should be trivial to write up multiple views to look at data from

**An Item Perspective**

```
CREATE VIEW ItemView
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM Items
END
```

**A Case Perspective**

```
CREATE VIEW CaseView
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT c.CaseBarCode
           ,Count(i.Id) As NumItems
    FROM   Items i JOIN Cases c ON i.CaseId = c.Id
    GROUP BY c.CaseBarCode
END
```

**A Pallet Perspective**

```
CREATE VIEW PalletView
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT p.PalletBarCode
           ,Count(c.Id) As NumCases
    FROM   Cases c JOIN Pallets p on c.PalletId = p.Id
    GROUP BY p.PalletBarCode
END
```